# How to calculate the viewing angle of an object in 3D

Tags: 3d, geometry, game-engine, coordinate-transformation

As shown below, assume there is a virtual camera pointing at an object and that both are defined by an orientation and position with respect to a global coordinate system. In the figures, black denotes the GCS and blue denotes a LCS.

[image: Problem]

Some objects, such as screens or LEDs in this case, have a viewing angle. They can only be seen, for example, if the angle to the observer is within ±70°

To solve this, so far I have taken the steps demonstrated by the following pseudo code. Where applicable, we are working in a right-handed coordinate system, using extrinsic rotations applied in the order ZYX.

```
LEDToWorldTransform = LED.Transform;
CameraToWorldTransform = Camera.Transform;
WorldToCameraTransform = CameraToWorldTransform.Inverse;
CameraToLEDTransform = WorldToCameraTransform * LEDToWorldTransform;
```

As I understand, CameraToLEDTransform should now contain the translation and rotation of the LED with respect to the camera coordinate system. For visualization purposes:

[image: Partial Solution]

Now this is where I get stuck, looking at the euler components of `CameraToLEDTransform` I think we can conclude that the Z component of the rotation with respect to the camera's coordinate system does not affect the viewing of the LED. I tried the following which I'm not sure is correct. Note, in the third step I'm trying to flip the direction of one of the Z axes such that they point in the same direction

```
R_Z, R_Y, R_X = CameraToLEDTransform.Rotation.Eulers
CameraToLEDTransform.Rotation.Eulers = 0, R_Y, R_X
CameraToLEDTransform.Rotation *= Rotation.AngleAxis[180deg,X]
Angle, Axis = CameraToLEDTransform.Rotation.AngleAxis
```

This gives an answer which sort of looks correct, however I suspect that something maybe wrong as following my logic I should also be able to replace the third step with:

```
CameraToLEDTransform.Rotation *= Rotation.AngleAxis[180deg,Y]
```

However, this is not the case and I get a different (and certainly wrong) answer. This approach may be completely wrong, and I certainly do not understand why rotating 180 around X differs from rotating 180 around Y in this situation. Perhaps an alternative approach would be to use the Dot product to calculate the angle, however I think this only works between two vectors not two rotations. It seems that projecting two new vectors based on the orientation of the two objects would be a very around about approach...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dot product is not a round about approach, it is the *correct* approach. You'll have to use the dot product between the view direction vector of the camera and the normal (i.e. vector from the observer to the LED/object in question) to get the cosine of the required angle. If the object is a *surface* like a screen, you may want to use the normal of the surface instead.

```
// normalized returns a unit vector
Vector3 normal = (led.position - observer.position).Normalized(); 
Vector3 lookDirection = observer.lookDirection; // Should be a unit vector

float cosAngle = Vector3.Dot(normal, lookDirection);
```

While checking if the angle falls within the required range, we can use the following property of the `cos` function to avoid an `acos` call:

> If `-angle <= theta <= angle`, `cos(theta) >= cos(angle)`. (Try it out!)

Your check would be as follows:

```
// You can constantize or precompute this
float cosViewingAngle = cos(deg2rad(70));
bool inViewingAngle = cosAngle >= cosViewingAngle;
```

Comment: You are correct. I had started with some bad assumptions that took me down the wrong path.